# access variables of outer class in Java

Tags: java, local-variables, anonymous-inner-class

in Java android application how can i access variables of outer class from the inner anonymous class ?
Example:

```
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    .....
    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) {

           //here i'd like to do something with **dialog** variable
           .......

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 29):

If the dialog variable is a field of the outer class, you can use `this` prefixed with the outer class name ([a qualified this](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/expressions.doc.html#251603)):

```
send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(View v) {
       ProgressDialog dlg = OuterClass.this.dialog;
       .......
    }
});
```

Alternatively, if the dialiog variable is a local variable it needs to be marked as final:

```
final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
.....
send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(View v) {
       // The dialog variable is in scope here ...
       dialog.someMethod();
    }
});
```

Comment: This is the correct answer when `dialog` is a field of the outer class. I think in this case it is a local variable in the method around the inner class.

Comment: Im glad java supports this so i dont have to come up with different weird name

Answer (score 4):

Make the outer local variable (`dialog`) `final` so you can refer to it from the inner class.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a local variable (like the signature suggests), it needs to be `final` for the inner class to be able to access it. If it's a member variable, the visibility modifier needs to be default (no modifier) or higher (protected or public). With `private` -modifier, it still works, but you might get a warning (depending on your compiler-settings):

> Read access to enclosing field SomeClass.someField is emulated by a
>   synthetic accessor method

Comment: The part about member variables is not true. Inner classes can access private members of the enclosing class -- the compiler generates hidden accessors for such members.