# Surprising access to fields with Java anonymous class

Tags: java, anonymous-class

I'm trying to better understand the concept of anonymous classes in Java. From other answers on this website, I learned that an anonymous class can access non-final fields of the enclosing class using `OuterClass.this.myField`.

I made the following simple test case with an interface, `AnonInt`, and a class `AnonTest` with a method `foo` which returns an instance of an anonymous class implementing `AnonInt`. Dspite the fact that I'm using `System.out.println(a)` rather than `System.out.println(AnonTest.this.a)` the code works and prints the correct result. How can this be?

```
public interface AnonInt {
    void print();
}

public class AnonTest {

    private int a;

    public AnonTest(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public AnonInt foo() {
        return new AnonInt() {

            public void print() {
                System.out.println(a);
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnonTest at = new AnonTest(37);
        AnonInt ai = at.foo();
        ai.print();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Despite the fact that I'm using `System.out.println(a)` rather than `System.out.println(AnonTest.this.a)` the code works and prints the correct result. How can this be?

Since the reference to `a` is unambiguous in your context, the two expressions reference the same field.

Generally, `AnonTest.this` is required in a very specific context - when your method needs to access `AnonTest` object itself, rather than accessing one of its members. In case of your program, this is unnecessary: the compiler resolves the expression `a` to the object `AnonTest.this.a`, and passes it to `System.out.println`.

Comment: Thanks! Could you comment on Rich O'Kelly's answer in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545076/access-variables-of-outer-class-in-java? Would you need 'OuterClass.this.dialog' to access 'dialog'? Thanks!

Comment: @AlexandreVandermonde Since the old question is somewhat unclear as to what else is in the class where the `dialog` field is defined, the answer tries to be conservative, and cover a possibility of a naming conflict between `dialog` in `OuterClass.this` and some other `dialog` field or variable that may be in scope as well. When the situation is unambiguous, he could scrap his `dlg` variable, and use `dialog` in its place.